# Search inside Android RecyclerView ArrayList

Tags: android, search, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a search option for my recyclerView, where the user can type a reference. But it looks like each time I type a charcacter in the search view my arrayList gets duplicated and even when I try to clear it, it dosent work:
 This the initial View:

[image: Initial View]

And this is the search Bug

[image: SearchView]

And this is my code for the search

```
         searchOnd.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            query.toLowerCase();
           filtredList.clear();
            for (Onduleur al:pvList){
                if(al.getReference().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*"))){
                    filtredList.add(al);
                }
            }
            if(filtredList.isEmpty()) {
                layInver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                notfound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                backSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                errorNotFound.setText(R.string.onduleur_404_search);
            }
            else{
                pvListC.addAll(pvList);
                pvList.removeAll(pvList);
                pvList.addAll(filtredList);
                backSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                inverterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(inverterAdapter);
                layInver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                slideDown= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_up);
                layInver.startAnimation(slideDown);
                layInver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

            filtredList=new ArrayList<Onduleur>();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            query.toLowerCase();
            filtredList.clear();
            for (Onduleur al:pvList){
                if(al.getReference().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*"))){
                    filtredList.add(al);
                }
            }
            if(filtredList.isEmpty()) {
                layInver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                notfound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                backSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                errorNotFound.setText(R.string.onduleur_404_search);
            }
                else{
                pvListC.addAll(pvList);
                pvList.removeAll(pvList);
                pvList.addAll(filtredList);
                backSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                inverterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(inverterAdapter);
                layInver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                slideDown= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_up);
                layInver.startAnimation(slideDown);
                layInver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

            filtredList=new ArrayList<Onduleur>();
            return true;
        }
    });
    searchOnd.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            notfound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pvList.clear();
            preparePVData();
            inverterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(inverterAdapter);
            layInver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            slideDown= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_up);
            layInver.startAnimation(slideDown);
            layInver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
 for (Onduleur al:pvList) {
                if(al.getReference().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*"))){
                    filtredList.add(al);
                }
            }
 for (Onduleur al:pvList) {
                if(al.getNomOnduleur().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*"))){
                    filtredList.add(al);
                }
            }
```

Do this:

```
for (Onduleur al:pvList) {
      if(al.getReference().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*")) || al.getNomOnduleur().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*"))){
          filtredList.add(al);
      }
}
```

Also:
Instead of `pvList.removeAll(pvList);` please do `pvList.clear();`

Comment: actually I removed the second For loop, but now the search dosen't work, I show the not found message even when there is matching items

Comment: can you update your question so I can see the current code?

Comment: So now you only have one if statment `if(al.getReference().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*")))` do you want to try to like I mentioned above? -`if(al.getReference().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*")) || al.getNomOnduleur().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*")))`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

You have **clear** your list before adding new items into it in order to prevent creation of duplicates then only add items to the list.

```
**flitredList.clear();**
for (Onduleur al:pvList){
    if(al.getReference().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*"))){
      filtredList.add(al);
    }
}
for (Onduleur al:pvList){
    if(al.getNomOnduleur().matches(("(.*)("+query+").*"))){
      filtredList.add(al);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

You have written same logic in both `onQueryTextSubmit()` and `onQueryTextChange`. Try **removing code** from `onQueryTextChange()` as this method will gets executed every time text changes. So items will get added into your list. That might be the reason for duplication.

Hope this helps.

Comment: He already does that.->  `filtredList=new ArrayList<Onduleur>();` is a new List which is em empty by default.

Comment: I opted for the clear like this answer, but now the search itself inside the arrayList dosen't work (no duplicates though)

Comment: @MeknessiHamida check solution 2 as well.